# Implementing Adiabatic Grover Search via QAOA

Tags: grovers-algorithm, qaoa, adiabatic-model

I am reading the paper [Grover Search Inspired Alternating Operator Ansatz of Quantum Approximate
Optimization Algorithm for Search Problems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.10324.pdf). The paper proposes running the Adiabatic Grover Search algorithm via QAOA. The product of $2p$ unitaries to be implemented via QAOA is given in Eq. 19 of the paper. One of the unitaries is of the form $e^{- i H_f}$, where $H_f = I - | \omega\rangle \langle \omega |$, where $ | \omega \rangle$ is the marked state that is to be found.

I am confused. Is it assumed that a black-box access to $H_f$ is given? The role played by $H_f$ seems analogous to the the role played by the oracle given in the gate based version of Grover's algorithm. How does one even implement this algorithm in practice? Knowing $H_f$ is crucial to implement it via QAOA!